# Programmatically uninstall browser extensions

Tags: browser, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions, browser-extension, browser-addons

With browsers ability to sync themselves, and reinstall extensions/BHOs.  I want to know how would one programatically uninstall extensions/BHOs.  I already have the old registry, and extension folder way, which no longer work.

I would like to do this with:

- Firefox
- Chrome

Comment: Maybe it's possible with Puppeteer or similar tool, check their documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [chrome.management.uninstall(string id, object options, function callback)](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management#method-uninstall)
 for chrome and [browser.management.uninstall](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/management/uninstall) for the firefox.

You only need pass an ID of extension to this method.

Comment: So if I don't have any browser up at all, is there a way to issue these outside the browser?

Comment: No, you can only do it from the extension or from another extension by passing id.

Comment: As you can see in the compatibility table Firefox doesn't implement `browser.management.uninstall` or `chrome.management.uninstall`.